# C error for passing argument from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUF_LEN 1024


int SendOut(char *SywUserIdTemp, char *IntractnIdBuf1, char *IntractnIdBuf2, char *IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    char *DivNbrBuf1, char *DivNbrBuf2, char *DivNbrBuf3, 
                    char *ItemNbrBuf1, char *ItemNbrBuf2, char *ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    char *KsnIdBuf1, char *KsnIdBuf2, char *KsnIdBuf3,
                    char *buddy_cntBuf1, char *buddy_cntBuf2, char *buddy_cntBuf3,
                    char *today_month, int all, int n1, int n2, int n3, char *summer_active_temp, char *winter_active_temp, FILE *fpOut)
{
    //function logic
    return(0);
}

int main(int argn, char* argv[])
{
    //initialize variables
    int i, all;
    //char SywUserId, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, cnt_rank, table_type, summer_active, summer_active_temp, winter_active, winter_active_temp, SywUserIdTemp;
    char *SywUserId, *IntractnId, *DivNbr, *ItemNbr, *KsnId, *buddy_cnt, *cnt_rank, *table_type, *summer_active, *winter_active, *summer_active_temp, *winter_active_temp, *SywUserIdTemp;
    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    char *IntractnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf1[BUF_LEN];
    char *IntractnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf2[BUF_LEN];
    char *IntractnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf3[BUF_LEN];
    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
    int nRow=0, iCount=0;

    //determine season
    char *today_month;
    time_t result = time(NULL);
    struct tm* today = (localtime(&result));
    char month_str[3];
    strftime(month_str, sizeof(month_str), "%m", today);
    if ( strcmp( month_str, "03" ) < 0 || strcmp( month_str, "08" ) > 0 ){
        today_month = "1"; //winter
    }
    else{
        today_month = "2"; //summer
    }

    //if input does not have 3 arguments terminate
    if(argn != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return(-1);
    }

    //check for input file
    fpIn = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fpIn == NULL) {
        printf("Error: no input file");
    }

    //check for output files
    fpOut = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(fpOut == NULL) {
        printf("Error: no output file");
    }
    // Skip the first row.
    //fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn); 
    // Process the data.
    fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn);
    SywUserIdTemp = "0";
    winter_active_temp = "0";
    summer_active_temp = "0";
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 0;
    n3 = 0;
    all = 0;
    while(!feof(fpIn)) {
        if(strlen(buf) < 2) break;
        // Remove CR or LF at the tail.
        i=strlen(buf)-1; while(i > 0 && buf[i] <= ' ') buf[i--] = '\0';
        SywUserId = strtok(buf, ",");
        table_type = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cnt_rank = strtok(NULL, ",");
        IntractnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
        DivNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        ItemNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        KsnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
        buddy_cnt = strtok(NULL, ",");
        summer_active = strtok(NULL, ",");
        winter_active = strtok(NULL, ",");
        printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", SywUserId, table_type, cnt_rank, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, summer_active, winter_active);

        //if it is the same member the ksn number is saved in a buffer to create pairs from
        if( strcmp(SywUserIdTemp, SywUserId) == 0 )
        {
            if( strcmp(table_type, "1") == 0 )
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf1[n1] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf1[n1] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf1[n1] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf1[n1] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf1[n1++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf1[n1], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf1[n1], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf1[n1], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf1[n1], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf1[n1++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(table_type, "2") == 0 )
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf2[n2] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf2[n2] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf2[n2] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf2[n2] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf2[n2++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf2[n2], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf2[n2], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf2[n2], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf2[n2], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf2[n2++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }
            else //table_type == 3
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf3[n3] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf3[n3] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf3[n3] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf3[n3] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf3[n3++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf3[n3], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf3[n3], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf3[n3], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf3[n3], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf3[n3++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }

            all++;
        }
        //else all the combos are created and written to the output file
        //the new mbrId is copied to the tempMbrId
        //the nKsn is reset to 0 and the new ksnId is saved in the buffer
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(table_type, "0") > 0 || strcmp(table_type, "0") < 0 )
            {
                SendOut(SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1, IntractnIdBuf2, IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    DivNbrBuf1, DivNbrBuf2, DivNbrBuf3, 
                    ItemNbrBuf1, ItemNbrBuf2, ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    KsnIdBuf1, KsnIdBuf2, KsnIdBuf3,
                    buddy_cntBuf1, buddy_cntBuf2, buddy_cntBuf3,
                    today_month, all, n1, n2, n3, summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp, fpOut);
            }
            //reset info
            SywUserIdTemp = SywUserId;
            summer_active_temp = summer_active;
            winter_active_temp = winter_active;
            n1 = 0;
            n2 = 0;
            n3 = 0;
            all = 0;
            if(strcmp(table_type, "1") == 0 )
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf1[n1] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf1[n1] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf1[n1] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf1[n1] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf1[n1++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf1[n1], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf1[n1], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf1[n1], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf1[n1], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf1[n1++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(table_type, "2") == 0)
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf2[n2] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf2[n2] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf2[n2] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf2[n2] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf2[n2++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf2[n2], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf2[n2], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf2[n2], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf2[n2], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf2[n2++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }
            else //table_type == 3
            {
                //IntractnIdBuf3[n3] = IntractnId;
                //DivNbrBuf3[n3] = DivNbr;
                //ItemNbrBuf3[n3] = ItemNbr;
                //KsnIdBuf3[n3] = KsnId;
                //buddy_cntBuf3[n3++] = buddy_cnt;
                strncpy(IntractnIdBuf3[n3], IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(DivNbrBuf3[n3], DivNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(ItemNbrBuf3[n3], ItemNbr, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(KsnIdBuf3[n3], KsnId, BUF_LEN - 1);
                strncpy(buddy_cntBuf3[n3++], buddy_cnt, BUF_LEN - 1);
            }

            all++;
            //printf("nKsn=%d", nKsn);
        }
        // Show the progress.
        nRow++;
        if( iCount < 999 ) {
            iCount++;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", nRow);
            iCount = 0;
        }
        fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn);
    }
    SendOut(SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1, IntractnIdBuf2, IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    DivNbrBuf1, DivNbrBuf2, DivNbrBuf3, 
                    ItemNbrBuf1, ItemNbrBuf2, ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    KsnIdBuf1, KsnIdBuf2, KsnIdBuf3,
                    buddy_cntBuf1, buddy_cntBuf2, buddy_cntBuf3,
                    today_month, all, n1, n2, n3, summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp, fpOut);

    //close files when done
    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);

    //exit program
    return(0);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 3 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 4 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 5 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 6 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 7 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 8 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 9 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 10 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 11 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 12 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 13 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 14 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 15 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 16 of âSendOutâ from incompatible pointer type
```

Could someone please explain why the pointer type is incompatible.  I know I am getting this same set of warnings each time I call the function at the top of the program.  Thanks.

Comment: No way I dig through all those function arguments. This is worse than WinAPI...

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are declared to be `char*`. You are passing `char**`. Hence the warning. For instance, to the second parameter you pass `IntractnIdBuf1` which is declared like this:

```
char *IntractnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN]
```

And so `IntractnIdBuf1` is an array that decays to a pointer of type `char**`.

I've not studied your code in more detail than that. But probably you need to change your declarations to:

```
char IntractnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN]
```

and so on.

Comment: I think that's enough information.

Answer (score 0):

These:

```
char *IntractnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf1[BUF_LEN];
char *IntractnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf2[BUF_LEN];
char *IntractnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], *DivNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], *ItemNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], *KsnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], *buddy_cntBuf3[BUF_LEN];
```

Are arrays of char*. Therefore they are technically char**s. The function argument wants char*s.